# HTML 5 Adding XML Namespaces

Tags: html, facebook, xml-namespaces

Can anyone tell me how you add additional XML namespaces to an HTML 5 document?

I'm trying to create an HTML 5 version of the following

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

Is it simply a case of dropping the xhtml namespace:

```
<html xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the WHATWG, in html 5 you are permitted to use the xmlns attribute on each html element as long as the namespace is http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml (the namespace of the document)

> **Will there be support for namespaces in HTML?**
>
> HTML is being defined in terms of the
>   DOM and during parsing of a text/html
>   all HTML elements will be
>   automatically put in the HTML
>   namespace,
>   http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml. However,
>   unlike the XHTML serialization, there
>   is no real namespace syntax available
>   in the HTML serialization (see
>   previous question). In other words,
>   you do not need to declare the
>   namespace in your HTML markup, as you
>   do in XHTML. However, you are
>   permitted to put an xmlns attribute on
>   each HTML element as long as the
>   namespace is
>   http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml